# Convert a QDateTime in UTC to local system time

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I construct a QDateTime from a string like this:

```
QDateTime date = QDateTime::fromString("2010-10-25T10:28:58.570Z", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.zzzZ");
```

I know that `date` is in UTC because that is the way it's stored. But when I want to display this date to the user, it should be in the user's local time zone. [`date.toLocalTime()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qdatetime.html#toLocalTime) looks promising, but it returns the exact same date!

How do I convert `date` to the system's local time to display to the user?

Here are some more failures:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore/QDateTime>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QDateTime date = QDateTime::fromString("2010-10-25T10:28:58.570Z", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.zzzZ");
    QDateTime local = date.toLocalTime();

    qDebug() << "utc: " << date;
    qDebug() << "local: " << local.toString();
    qDebug() << "hax: " << local.toString(Qt::SystemLocaleLongDate);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
utc:  QDateTime("Mon Oct 25 10:28:58 2010")
local:  "Mon Oct 25 10:28:58 2010"
hax:  "Monday, October 25, 2010 10:28:58 AM"
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

QDateTime knows whether it is UTC or local time. For example:

```
QDateTime utc = QDateTime::currentDateTimeUtc();
QDateTime local = QDateTime::currentDateTime();

local.secsTo(utc) // zero; these dates are the same even though I am in GMT-7
```

We need to tell `date` that it is a UTC date time with `date.setTimeSpec(Qt::UTC)`:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore/QDateTime>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QDateTime date = QDateTime::fromString("2010-10-25T10:28:58.570Z", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.zzzZ");
    date.setTimeSpec(Qt::UTC);
    QDateTime local = date.toLocalTime();

    qDebug() << "utc: " << date;
    qDebug() << "local: " << local.toString();
    qDebug() << "hax: " << local.toString(Qt::SystemLocaleLongDate);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
utc:  QDateTime("Mon Oct 25 10:28:58 2010") 
local:  "Mon Oct 25 03:28:58 2010" 
hax:  "Monday, October 25, 2010 3:28:58 AM"
```

I'm in GMT-7, so this is right.

Answer (score 0):

Is using [QDateTime::toString()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qdatetime.html#toString-2) not giving you expected results ?

Maybe you could try using a different format with `QDateTime::toString(Qt::SystemLocaleLongDate)` or `QDateTime::toString(Qt::SystemLocaleShortDate)`.

Otherwise, I would try to use [QLocale::dateTimeFormat()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qlocale.html#dateTimeFormat) to get the local format as a `QString` and then use this string as the format parameter of [QDateTime::toString()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qdatetime.html#toString), but I don't think it will change anything.