# Convert System::Datetime to QDateTime

Tags: c++, .net, qt, qdatetime

How can I convert [System::Datetime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) to [QDateTime](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html)?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030511/convert-a-qdatetime-in-utc-to-local-system-time) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30930959/5653461) from another question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QDateTime Conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30930085/qdatetime-conversion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QDateTime::fromString(QString::fromStdWString(msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::wstring>(systemDateTime.ToString("ddMMyyyy HH:mm:ss"))), "ddMMyyyy HH:mm:ss"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is straightforward method, but it can be easy for understating:

a) convert System::Datetime to string with `DateTime.ToString()`

b) convert string to QDateTime with `QDateTime::fromString()`

Or consider usage of `QDateTime::fromTime_t()` (see example of [Datetime to time_t conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265481/standard-conformant-way-of-converting-stdtime-t-to-systemdatetime))

Answer (score 0):

using Win32 API

```
#define WINDOWS_TICKS_PER_SEC 10000000
#define EPOCH_DIFFERENCE 11644473600LL

QDatetime getQDatetime(){
    FILETIME ft = {0}; 
    ::GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ft);  //Retrieves the current system date and time.
    LARGE_INTEGER li = {0};
    li.LowPart = ft.dwLowDateTime;
    li.HighPart = ft.dwHighDateTime;
    long long int hns = li.QuadPart;
    wprintf(L"Windows API time: %lli\n", hns);
    long long int utm ;
    utm=(hns / WINDOWS_TICKS_PER_SEC - EPOCH_DIFFERENCE);
    wprintf(L"Unix time: %lli\n", utm);
    return QDateTime::fromTime_t(utm);
}
```

[See this for more help](http://zetcode.com/gui/winapi/datetime/)

Comment: Convert Windows Filetime to second in Unix/Linux : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6161842/2731967

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **ISO 8601** norm as intermediate format :

```
/* not tested */
System::DateTime date;
QString str(date.ToString("O")); // "O" for ISO format
QDateTime qdt = QDateTime::fromString(str, Qt::ISODate);
```

See [`QDateTime::fromString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdatetime.html#fromString) and [`DateTime::ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_8) docs